# Multiple repeated groups pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Here is the question and required solution:
1.First Case:

```
String str = "Variable_1 in the range 0...4";
```

Solution: `var1 = Variable_1 Range = 0...4`

```
 Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(.*[^.]) in the range of (.*[^.])$");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(desc);

    if (m1.find()) {
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));
        System.out.println(m1.group(2));
    }
```

2.Second Case:

```
String str = "Variable_1 in the range 0...4 Variable_2 in the range 10...40";
```

Solution:
`var1 = Variable_1 range1 = 0...4 var2 = Variable_2 range2 = 10...40`

3.Third Case:

```
String str = "Variable_1 in the range 0...4 Variable_2 in the range 10...40 Variable_3 in the range 10...50";
```

Solution: 
`var1 = Variable_1 range1 = 0...4 var2 = Variable_2 range2 = 10...40 var3 = Variable_3 range3 = 10...50`

The first case works fine with the regex. I need to extend the same regex for the second and third cases. It should also be able to handle for n number of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `of` in your pattern is redundant, you may use

```
(\w+) in the range (\d+\.+\d+)
```

Or, if your strings contain `of`, then add it, `(\w+) in the range of (\d+\.+\d+)`. `\w+` will match one or more letters, digits or underscores. `\d+\.+\d+` matches 1+ digits, 1+ dots, 1+ digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dc3MUd/1)

[Java demo:](https://ideone.com/h42puA)

```
String lines[]  = {"Variable_1 in the range 0...4",
    "Variable_1 in the range 0...4 Variable_2 in the range 10...40",
    "Variable_1 in the range 0...4 Variable_2 in the range 10...40 Variable_3 in the range 10...50"
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) in the range (\\d+\\.+\\d+)");
for(String line : lines)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Variable_1 in the range 0...4
Variable_1
0...4
Variable_1 in the range 0...4 Variable_2 in the range 10...40
Variable_1
0...4
Variable_2
10...40
Variable_1 in the range 0...4 Variable_2 in the range 10...40 Variable_3 in the range 10...50
Variable_1
0...4
Variable_2
10...40
Variable_3
10...50
```

Comment: Further down the line if I have to break the range part to min and  max, how does the pattern look like?            For example: -10...10, -32768...32767, -3.2...3.2, 0...10